# How to add a 'X' to the end of every line in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to append a capital `'X'` character at the end of every line of a simple text file (while switching all chars to upper case at the same time) and writing the changes to a new file.

So initially, the file `faust.txt` contains:

```
Besonders aber laßt genug geschehn!
Man kommt zu schaun, man will am liebsten sehn.
Wird vieles vor den Augen abgesponnen,
```

After the call, the file `FAUST.txt` should contain:

```
BESONDERS ABER LAßT GENUG GESCHEHN!X
MAN KOMMT ZU SCHAUN, MAN WILL AM LIEBSTEN SEHN.X
WIRD VIELES VOR DEN AUGEN ABGESPONNEN,X
```

The copying and conversion to upper case seems to work but the appending is unclear to me:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    // 1)  Open faust source file 
    int BUF_SIZE = 1;
    int faust_fh = open("faust.txt", O_RDONLY);
    char src[BUF_SIZE];

    // Destination file.
    int FAUST_fh = open("FAUST.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);

    int read_bytes = read(faust_fh, &src, BUF_SIZE);
    while (read_bytes > 0) {

        char c = src[0];
        char *C = &c; 
        src[0] = toupper(*C);

        if (src[0] == '\n') {
            char *end = &src[0];
            strcat(end, "X");
            src[0] = *end;
        }   

        write(FAUST_fh, &src, BUF_SIZE);
        read_bytes = read(faust_fh, src, BUF_SIZE);
    }   

    close(FAUST_fh);
    close(faust_fh);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I should accomplish this with system calls (if possible).

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. You're using `strcat()`, but `end` is not a zero-terminated string.

Comment: Also, `CHAR src[BUF_SIZE]` only has room for 1 character. It doesn't have room for the null terminator or for concatenating `X`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni As I wrote, the writing of the upper-cased text works.

Comment: You're only writing `1` byte at a time, and it's always the first character of `src`. So you never write the `X` that you append.

Comment: If this is just an exercise in system calls, i'm not sure why you're even trying to buffer content. Just reading `char` one at a time, special-casing a newline `'\n'` to dump an extra `'X'`, then regardless reflecting the char just-read back to your output file, first converted via `toupper`, would seem to fil your stated requirements whilst being considerably easier to implement.

Comment: @WhozCraig I would love to find the simplest possible solution, don't get me wrong on that.. instruction wise I have currently no other knowledge but to use buffers when copying from one file to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `BUF_SIZE` is 1, you are reading the input character by character.

This is fine, but this also mean that `src` is just a one-char array, not a nul-terminated string (an array of characters terminated by `'\0'` character).

And this mean all string manipulation functions, such as `strcat` cannot be used. All of them lead to *undefined behavior* when it comes to deal with araays that are not null-terminated..

In order to accomplish your task, just perform an extra `write` whenever you find an end of line:

```
if (src[0] == '\n') {
    char ecs = 'X';
    write(FAUST_fh, &ecs, 1);
    // it's always recommended to check the return value of write()
}
```

All the other characters will be appended as usual. The `X` char write is just an insertion on the fly.

Comment: "inserting a write on the fly": That's the insight i needed.

Comment: My reason for using a buffer of size 1 is that I wouldn't know otherwise how to make this check `src[0] == '\n'`, because which index would I write then (instead of `0`)?

Comment: @tmottm how I wrote, that's fine. Alternatively you could read chunks of data and perform this byte-by-byte parsering on the input buffer preparing an output buffer with the same logic. Anyway, without the syscalls constraint I'd just use fgets. Having a big enough buffer you could easily do your manipulation at the end of the buffer, after finding the new line with `strcspn ()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're causing undefined behavior when you call `strcat(end, "X");` because `end` points to `src`, and `src` doesn't have a null terminator and doesn't have enough bytes allocated to concatenate anything.

If you're reading the file one byte at a time, you don't need an array. Just read into a `char` variable. When the character is a newline, write an `X` to the output file before writing the character.

Another problem: when you call `open()` to create the output file, you have to pass a third argument containing the desired file permissions.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    // 1)  Open faust source file 
    int BUF_SIZE = 1;
    int faust_fh = open("faust.txt", O_RDONLY);
    char src;

    // Destination file.
    int FAUST_fh = open("FAUST.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);

    int read_bytes = read(faust_fh, &src, BUF_SIZE);
    while (read(faust_fh, &src, BUF_SIZE) > 0) {
        src = toupper(src);
        if (src == '\n') {
            write(FAUST_fh, "X", 1);
        }
        write(FAUST_fh, &src, BUF_SIZE);
    }   

    close(FAUST_fh);
    close(faust_fh);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We need: `int FAUST_fh = open("FAUST.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);` --> `int FAUST_fh = open("FAUST.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);` When I was testing my own version, I got an output file with an `ls` of `----------.`

Comment: Thanks, added that fix.

Comment: @CraigEstey On Ubuntu seems like i get 755 permissions for FAUST.txt but thanks for mentioning anyway.

Comment: @Barmar OK essentially it also comes down to an on-the-fly write inside the if-statement.

Comment: @TMOTTM If you leave out the argument, it will use whatever garbage happens to be in the stack, so the result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

The caveats about `strcat` et. al. from other responders apply (e.g. you can't guarantee the buffer will have an EOS, so you can't use string functions).

Although it may be easiest to do a `read` with length 1, it's sometimes more efficient to have a larger buffer size.

Here's a version that works with buffer sizes > 1. I set a size of 10, but it can be whatever size you'd like:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(void)
{

    // 1) Open faust source file
#if 0
    int BUF_SIZE = 1;
#else
    int BUF_SIZE = 10;
#endif
    int faust_fh = open("faust.txt", O_RDONLY);
    char src[BUF_SIZE];
    char Xnewline[] = "X\n";

    // Destination file.
    // NOTE/BUG: we need to specify the mode with O_CREAT otherwise the
    // file is created with a semi-random permission mask
#if 0
    int FAUST_fh = open("FAUST.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
#else
    int FAUST_fh = open("FAUST.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
#endif

    char *lhs;
    size_t len;
    int read_bytes;

    while (1) {
        lhs = src;

        read_bytes = read(faust_fh, lhs, BUF_SIZE);
        if (read_bytes <= 0)
            break;

        char *end = &lhs[read_bytes];
        char *cur;

        // process/scan all bytes in the buffer
        for (cur = lhs;  cur < end;  ++cur) {
            int c = *cur;

            *cur = toupper(c);

            if (c == '\n') {
                // send all data up to, but not including the newline
                len = cur - lhs;
                if (len > 0)
                    write(FAUST_fh,lhs,len);

                // send X<newline>
                write(FAUST_fh,Xnewline,2);

                // set new left start into current buffer (just _past_ the
                // newline)
                lhs = cur + 1;
            }
        }

        // send the remainder of the current buffer [has _no_ newlines in it]
        len = cur - lhs;
        if (len > 0)
            write(FAUST_fh,lhs,len);
    }

    close(FAUST_fh);
    close(faust_fh);

    return 0;
}
```